# Not able to display images from particular directory IOS

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create image from this location :

```
NSString *documentsCacheDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; 
 NSString *fileName = @"image1.jpg";
 NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsCacheDirectory, fileName];
```

So applying to my Image :

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:filePath];
```

..setting this image as background to my button etc. etc.

But I'm not seeing any images displayed. However when I use the same technique for reading a file :

```
  NSString *documentsCacheDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]; 
         NSString *fileName = @"file.txt";
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsCacheDirectory, fileName];
    NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

for (NSString *line in [cacheFileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
.....
}
```

Reading file works just fine, but image does not, any reasons why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imageNamed:` is for images that are bundled with your app, you don't use this with a path. Use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead.